# Our eyes have remained the same size

Tags: predicative-complement, linking-verbs

> Our eyes have remained the same size.

In this sentence, I can't think what is
the role of '**the same size**' ?
is it object of **remained** or
is it a complement ?
Please explain this to me briefly.

Answer (score 4):

I think considering it an *intransitive verb* is not technically wrong, but it would be more accurate to consider the verb *(have) **remain**(ed)* a **[linking verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb)**.

And that would make ***the same size*** a **[complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement)**.

A simple test I usually use is to replace the verb with ***be***, if the sentence still has a similar meaning, it's quite likely that the verb is a linking verb. (But don't forget to check your dictionary, just to be sure!)